# how python opencv detect ROI together with number arrounded

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image here:

[image]

I wanna locate the question number, i.e.:

[image]

So, generally, for normal shape, I can use shape detection or template matching for this guy:

[image]

However, there is number within the region.

Anyone know this situation?

Opencv: 3.2.0

Python: 2.7.10

**Edit 1**

Here is code for template matching:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('papere1.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('no.png',0)
#template = cv2.imread('2.jpg',0)
#template = cv2.imread('papere3.jpg',0)
#cv2.imshow('origin',img_rgb)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold = 0.4

loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
print loc
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):

    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Detected',img_rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And here is template png:

[image]

However, target comes up only when I set threshold < 0.45, and even this target is not accurate...

**Edit 2**

with above code set threshold to 0.6, I got this:

[image]

So, seems good, but we can see target with 6 is missed. And I think the more digit number within target will get the lower match.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try template matching? I think the correlation would still be high even if there is a number in the shape.

Comment: Hi, see my edit 1 above, correlation is poor and not accurate.

Comment: Hmm, better now with the edit. If you know for all your images the destination would always be on the left 15% of the image, I would suggest that you crop it, and run template matching for atleast 10 pyramids of the image/template and check them. This is a dirty method but may be it works.

Comment: [You might want to see this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/)

Comment: I see the link you post but seems not what I want. It's more related to scale match. Actually, my situation is template dimensions is almost same with target in origin image. But the link is useful since we might hit the problem later on :-)

Comment: So did this solve your problem? May be you can dilate your image and template and try. You should get better results, not worse for sure

Comment: sorry, not yet :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140080/discussion-between-rick-m-and-wesley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following discussion in comments and chat,

The Steps to do to achieve this are as follows:

*Pre-requisite* - If you don't want to implement pyramid for template matching (if it isn't required due to overkill), make sure the template is as big as the one in the main image.

**Step 1** : Run `cv2.matchTemplate` with appropriate correlation measure.

**Step 2** : Set an appropriate threshold for the measure for correct detection.

**Step 3**: The OP mentioned the squares having digits so digit recognition from [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/) and setting the pixels for the contours as black and then running `cv2.matchTemplate` should work as well.

PS. The OP mentioned doing digit recognition after detecting the squares so this kind of solves the other problem too.